# Filling a corner

Tags: mesh

Somehow I have managed to mess up the corner of wall of my house.
The left side of the image shows what it currently looks like, and the right side shows more or less what it should look like.

I tried a simple "Grid Fill", but I guess that is not what I need.

Could somebody tell me how he would fix this? I was thinking that I could perhaps use the remaining 2 faces on the bottom of the corner, but I am not sure.
[image]

Comment: You can use those 2 vertices in the bottom. Just turn on `Snap during transform` with `Shift`+`Tab`, set it in Vertex mode, select vertices and extrude along `Z`. Then you can use `Alt` + `F` or something like that to fill faces

Comment: Unfortunately the vertices are not placed exactly on the grid, so the snapping does not work.

Comment: It will, if you select snap to Vertex. You can see my answer for more info

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood how it works. I thought I had to press Shift+Tab at the beginning of the extrusion procedure. I did not understand that I had to extrude and when the extrusion is near to where I want it, I THEN have to press Shift+Tab. Now it works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select those two vertices in the bottom. Turn on vertex snapping with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and selecting `Vertex`.

[image: fixing_1]

Use <kbd>E</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> to extrude along `Z`, and hover your mouse over adjacent vertices of the mesh:

[image: fixing 2]

To fill the faces quickly, create an edge on the topmost loop. To do that, select top one extruded vertice and one from the top loop. Make edge with <kbd>F</kbd>. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to fill faces, then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to get rid of triangles. Do that for another side.
[image: fixing_3]

Comment: it would've been much simpler to extrude one of the long edges.

Comment: hm.. Yeap. Proposal of OP made me blind.

Comment: Depending upon the purpose to which you wish to put your house, you might want to delete the faces in the ends of the walls before filling in the geometry.

Comment: @brasshat and that's another thing I didn't think of. Btw it can be done very simple by `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Alt`+`M`, or typing 'Select non-manifold'. So there were so many corrections to the answer that I feel  I should rewrite it